# How to apply TinyMCE on a textarea in Plone?

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

Say I have a textarea-tag with the id "the-textarea", how would one apply TinyMCE on it, in Plone?

Comment: Oh great, I just read the intro "If you are using Mockup ..." and skipped the rest, but awesomely you provide links to real-world-examples not using Mockup, thanks a bunch. It'll take a moment until I can come back to this and will share the result :-) Mods: Feel free to close as dup.